# Undefined return data in async function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to do a DB search and then return all data as an array but the await part is returning undefined

I've console.logged the array and it printed the results fine but then outside it says undefined

```
async function followUsersIds(user_id) {

    const following = await Follow.find({ "user": user_id })
        .select({ '_id': 0, '__v': 0, 'user': 0 }) //Evitar que traiga esos campos
        .exec((err, follows) => {
            if (err)
                return res.status(500).json({ ok: false, msg: `Error ${err}` })

            let following_clean = [];
            follows.forEach((follow) => {
                following_clean.push(follow.user_followed);
            });

            return following_clean;
        });


    return {
        following
    }
}
```

and here's the call:

```
followUsersIds(user_id)
                    .then((value) => {
                        console.log(value);
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            ok: true,
                            usuarios,
                            users_following: value.following,
                            total: conteo,
                            pages: Math.ceil(conteo / limite)
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => { return res.json({ ok: false, msg: `Error ${err}` }) })
```

BUT I'm not getting the "users_following" and if I console log the "value" it prints { following: undefined }

Comment: you use followUsersIds as it would be a promise  `followUsersIds(user_id)
                    .then(` . but is not a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up callbacks and async/await syntax

this is async/await syntax :

```
const following = await Follow.find({ "user": user_id })
```

This is callback syntax :

```
exec((err, follows) => {
```

---

```
try {
  // We get a Promise object from exec() that we resolve
  // We use a || [] to initialize following with an empty array
  // in case nothing got foung in database
  const following = (await Follow.find({
      user: user_id,
    })
    .select({
      _id: 0,
      __v: 0,
      user: 0,
    })
    .exec()) || [];

  // We build a new array containing only the wanted data
  const following_clean = following.map(x => x.user_followed);

  console.log(following_clean);
} catch (err) {
  // Handle the error
  return res.status(500).json({
    ok: false,
    msg: `Error ${err}`,
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for reply but it's still returning undefined { ok: false,
  msg: 'Error ReferenceError: follow is not defined' }   and UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

Comment: hm sorry wrong copy paste, be sure to have `following.map(x => x.user_followed);`